# Eclipse IDE fails when processing and even with "JVM Terminated. Exit code=1"

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

thank you in advance for any reply.

Currently I work with Eclipse Luna(version 4.4) and cannot open up certain windows without the program crashing with the following error. Even the help menu will crash the application.

I am currently using the OS: *Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 29 10:16:43 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.* This is a redhat distro of ubuntu.

[image]

I have read in other posts that I need to edit my .eclipse.ini file, but those descriptions are not specific as to how to change the .ini.For example i may need to change the RAM size, and i am not sure what to change it too.

**Would anyone here know how to fix this, or correctly edit the .ini file?**

UPDATE: I ran the application via console and got this.

(jfvorwal)/eclipse/4.4 > /eclipse/4.4/.eclipse $*
java: cairo-misc.c:380: _cairo_operator_bounded_by_source: Assertion `NOT_REACHED' failed.
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "abort", detail "" at 2015/07/13 15:58:31 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/eclipse/4.4/core.20150713.155831.11044.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP030W Cannot write dump to file /eclipse/4.4/core.20150713.155831.11044.0001.dmp: Permission denied
JVMDUMP012E Error in System dump: Unable to derive system core filename from pattern in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern: "core.%t.%p". "%t" specifier is not supported. Look for core file generated by child process with pid = 11173
JVMDUMP030W Cannot write dump to file /eclipse/4.4/javacore.20150713.155831.11044.0002.txt: Permission denied
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/javacore.20150713.155831.11044.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /tmp/javacore.20150713.155831.11044.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/eclipse/4.4/Snap.20150713.155831.11044.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP030W Cannot write dump to file /eclipse/4.4/Snap.20150713.155831.11044.0003.trc: Permission denied
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /tmp/Snap.20150713.155831.11044.0003.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "abort", detail "".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default value "256m/256M" from the eclipse configuration file (eclipse.ini).

Still no success?

Edit Path, on your Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Path

Set jdk directory properley.